# Does 'I think' make a statement more euphemistic?

Tags: politeness

Does adding 'I think' before a statement about others' behaviours, opinions, characters or the like make it more euphemistic? Say, compare

> 1'. You're wrong.
>
> 1''. I think you're wrong.
>
> 2'. You're a bit judgmental.
>
> 2''. I think you're a bit judgmental.

To me, a statement without 'I think' sounds like the speaker take it to be an undoubtful truth, while 'I think' may indicate the speaker is not so sure. So, I reckon 'I think' has some effect on listeners' feeling. (This 'I reckon' is not intended to have this effect. It's just the usual meaning 'I believe'.)

Come to think of it, I used tons of 'I think' before a statement just to be a bit more euphemistic or less ignorant. Now, I doubt it has that effect.

Comment: 'I think my cousin is an idiot' is different from 'I think there's a mouse in the house'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yeah, so I restricted the question in the very first sentence to the statements about people.

Comment: OK, 'I think Peter is a Scotsman'.

Comment: Cogito ergo sum

Comment: It often softens the statement. I would not call it euphemism, though I can see why you used the word.

Comment: @RonaldSole What do you mean? If I recall correctly, 'cogito ergo sum', not out of context, originally means only the very fact I'm doubting *can't be doubted/must be truth*. Are you saying I'm *overthinking about/overanalysing* the phrase?

Comment: @Michael Ronald Sole is making a joke. "*Cogito ergo sum*" translates from Latin as "**I think**, therefore I am." This isn't at all the meaning of "I think" you're asking about.

Comment: @Michael Are you sure you're understand the word "euphemistic" correctly? It means saying something acceptable in place of something unacceptable, in a way that people understand what you're really talking about. Like my grandmother would never say the word "underwear", so she used the euphemism, "unmentionables". Saying "I think" doesn't avoid saying anything offensive. It just says it less strongly. It's a *hedge*, not a euphemism.

Comment: @gotube I'm not sure.  :(  It expresses the nearest meaning among what I got from several translators. I meant that 'I think' might make it sounds less aggressive.

Comment: @Michael Yeah, that's not what "euphemistic" means. Is your question about the function of "I think" or about the word "euphemistic"?

Comment: About the function of ‘I think’.

Comment: "I think" is expressing an opinion and is admitting that others may think differently.

Comment: This reminds me of a stand-up act I saw on TV once. The comedian joked that you can say anything, no matter how offensive, and as long as you say "I'm just sayin'" afterward, the listener won't be offended. (I searched on Youtube but couldn't find the routine unfortunately.)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan - when people in the UK say 'I'm not being funny, but...' you know something offensive is about to be said.

Answer (score 2):

Not "euphemistic". That means replacing words that are too harsh.

> He is unemployed. -> He is between jobs.

> He is wrong. -> He has been misinformed.

Just adding "I think" expresses an opinion, not a fact. A point of view not objective truth.  As gotube says in a comment, it is a *hedge*, not a euphemism.